# onAppear does not take into account the height of the row

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to implement asynchronous image loading and I noticed that `onAppear` is triggering for the first 20 rows (on iPhone XR and 13 rows on iPhone SE) even though only 3-4 rows are visible.

```
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(1..<100) { (i) in
                    RowView(rowId: i)
                    .frame(height: 300)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct RowView : View {
    @State var image: Image = Image(systemName: "photo")

    var rowId: Int

    var body: some View {

        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            HStack {
                Text("Row \(rowId)")
                Spacer()
            }
            self.image
                .resizable()
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    print("Row \(self.rowId) appeared")
                })
            }
    }
}
```

If you replace the `RowView` with just `Text` and remove the `frame`, the first 20 rows are indeed visible so I can sort of understand why this happens (i.e. something related to the order of when the `frame` is evaulated vs. when the `onAppear` is triggered)

Is there any way to make `onAppear` trigger only when the row is actually visible?

Comment: Can you redirect the access on the `rowID` through a computed getter where you print that it was accessed and return the rowID itself, and remove `onAppear`? To see whether this is viable. You can also try to move the .fame-part into RowView

Comment: I think that the problem is that ForEach creates the RowViews and then the resizing causes them to disappear. If you add an onDisappear to the image you can see that the unseen ones disappear after the 20th appears.